# How to validate Mobile number for different countries

Tags: java, javascript, regex, validation, client-side-validation

the length of mobile number varies from country to country. Tired regular expresssion but (Ex:India allows 10 digits, which is not validating UAE which ranges from 7 to 9 digits)

Comment: Within one country, it may vary from provider to provider. - What is your question?

Comment: laune thanks for your reply. My Question is i have users from different countries, from UI screen the will add mobile numbers, so how can i write mobile number validation logic for different users based on there country. I have tried with Regex. but as country differ i need to change my Regex. I was in search of Generic code

Answer (score 2):

you can try using Google's phone number library. It contains the `isValidNumber`function which provides "full validation of a phone number for a region using length and prefix information".
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: can i use it as lib in my project which is in java

Comment: Yes. There is a java library within that project: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/java

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```